# I accidently changed the cursor image in Unity

Tags: unity, mouse, editors

In the Unity Editor I accidently changed the image for the mouse cursor in project settings > player

How can I restore it to the default, preferably not through programming?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "Default Cursor" texture again and select "None"

[image: Screenshot of player settings in Unity showing selection of "None" texture for cursor]